# Transistor as an OR gate switch to power up without voltage drop

Tags: power-supply, transistors, switches, logic-gates

I'm using the following circuit:
[image]

The swtich is a 3 position SPST, 1- connects COM1 to NO1, 2- OFF 3- connects COM2 to NO2.
I want to use the circuit to control LCD, PCB and MCU. The LCD should turn on if MCU or PCB are ON and turns OFF if they are OFF.
However the voltage drops (probably 0.7v) when Q1 turns ON (same for Q2 expected) and as a result the LCD stops working. I increased the 5v voltage to 5.7 and problem was solved but I should not change it.

- I changed the resistors to 100 ohm and it didn't change that much.
- I moved the load to emmiter and it was just worst.
- when I connect LCD directly to 1 transistor it works fine with 5v
  (seems odd to me).
- PCB and DC/DC convertor have low current usage around 200 to 500 mA.
- an LED and an op-AMP will be parallel to LCD but even if they are not
  connected the circuit is not working as I expect.

What could be the simplest way to solve this problem?

Comment: BJTs used as switches will always have a voltage drop between collector and emitter when on. The minimum voltage drop is typically around 200 mV, but can in some cases be as low as 100 mV. MOSFETs may have a much smaller voltage drop. Sometimes in the 10s of mV, but it depends on the MOSFET, the gate voltage, and the  drain current.

Comment: Also your 1K base resistor probably doesn't provide enough base current to get the BJT fully into saturation.  The min hfe is 20 at 4 A.  You're better off finding a single logic-level MOSFET, using a pull-down on the gate and (Schottky) diode-oring  the control signal to the gate.